# Ajax loader effects in jquery/css (i.e. not ajaxload.info)

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, effects

Does any know any simple library that can generate some "loading" effects without using any images?

The reason why i'm asking is that i've been using ajaxload.info now and then, but it only really works well on a solid background color.. with a background gradient or pattern, it looks bad... it's also annoying to have to re-generate one for each solid background color.

Anything out there that could work?

Doesn't have to be complicated. Just a few animation effects to give some feedback..

Answer (score 0):

if you have problems with the gradients,
just choose a loader template that is confined in a box like: kit/bar/bar2/bar3..

if you don't want to work with an animated gif you can use css3 but then it won't work on older browsers,
and you can play with some jQuery animations - like animating the text "Loading..." look here for example: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fun-with-jquerys-animate/

[edit]
taking james padolsey's example, here is a running demo of an object to animate a text of a given div to show loading:
http://jsbin.com/ifiki3/edit

**BTW' - i would still use a loading jif for this task..**

this is a quick example - you can tidy the code as you like

here is the code(but i would just go to the jsBin link):

```
function AnimateText(contSelector)
{

  this.cont = jQuery(contSelector);
  this.isRunning = false;
  this.animText = this.cont.text();
  this.duration = 1000;
  this.cont.hide();
}
AnimateText.prototype.Start = function()
{
  this.cont.show();
  this.isRunning = true;
  this.AnimateText();
}

AnimateText.prototype.Stop = function()
{
  this.cont.hide();
  this.isRunning = false;
}

AnimateText.prototype.AnimateText = function()
{
  if(this.isRunning === false)
  {
    return;
  }
  var animObj = this;
  var len = animObj.animText.length;
  jQuery({count:0}).animate({count:len}, {
      duration: animObj.duration,
    complete: function(){animObj.AnimateText();},
      step: function() {
          animObj.cont.text( animObj.animText.substring(0, Math.round(this.count)) );
      }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  var animText = new AnimateText("#Loader");
  animText.Start();
  jQuery("#stopLoading").click(function(){animText.Stop()});
});
```

at the HTML:

```
  <div id="Loader">Loading...</div>
  <div id="stopLoading">click me to stop Loading</div>
```

Comment: @avi. Thanks for your input. I'm aware of these options. I'm looking for a library that would offer some base loader effects in js/css. I don't particularily want to write one.

Comment: @avi, thanks again for publishing a working example. I would prefer something that renders a js/css loader rather than animating some text, but it's a great attempt.

Comment: js loader == animating something in a loop till you stop it :) just change the inner animation function inside the object to animate a css property or something. pure css will not work on older browsers.

Comment: oh.. and if you can't find something that satisfies you - build something awesome and release it to the wild for others to use :)

Comment: @avi. Thanks I appreciate your input.. I was really hoping someone would have built a library already... I guess I was wrong.

Comment: i'm not sure you are wrong, i have never looked for a plugin like this, maybe someone have built it.